# AWS basic lamda function using java 21

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have basic knowledge on core java and basic java programs and im trying to implement simple java programs in aws lamda

```
public class Chatgpttasks
{
    public int addition(int a, int b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to run this jar package in aws lamda but I'm getting the below error

```
{
  "errorMessage": "No public method named addition with appropriate method signature found on class com.tasks.Chatgpttasks"
}
```

previously I executed this  and it worked well

```
package com.second;

public class  Democlass
{
    public String functiontwo(String name)
    {
        return "hello" + name;
    }

}
```

can someone help me with this? I'm new to everything

Comment: Have you seen the [samples](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-samples.html)?

Comment: in the samples please note you have to implement proper interface (RequestHandler) with request and response types based on how the lambda is invoked (directly, api, s3 events, sns,...)